# Ubuntu Live: Disable Keyboard Shortcut Overlay on first boot

Tags: 14.04, unity, live-usb, live-environment

I am working on an Ubuntu 14.04 Live system.

On every boot it displays the same *"Keyboard Shortcuts"* overlay that is shown when you press the *Super key* for two seconds.

[image]

This is a nice feature for a normal install, but I would like to disable it for the live system.

I have tried running this in the *chroot* (used for creating the live system) and on *startup* (using `/etc/rc.local`) but it doesn't help.

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/shortcut-overlay false
```

How can I disable this overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying I figured out a way.

My final solution is adding the file */etc/profile.d/overlay.sh*. In it I have this line, which disables the overlay (same effect as the command in the question).

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ shortcut-overlay false
```

This file is executed whenever a user logs in, so it even works when it's the first time.